# vscode build-in plugin typescript configure "typescript.format.enable": false didn't work

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I had set something like `quote_type = single` in `.editorconfig` 、`.prettierrc`、`.eslintrc`

```
// workspace
// .vscode/settings.json
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true,         
    },
    "typescript.format.enable": false,//did not work
}
```

**Question**: How to disable VS Code build-in typescript.format and make prettier rules effective

Answer (score 0):

you may try this in your vscode settings

```json
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```